# How to add new post to swiper.js html

Tags: html, swiper.js

I just add 3d swiper.js to my html page. I would like to add new posts to this slider time to time when i publish the web site. How can I do that? Is there any way explained. Thanks

Comment: Create a minimum reproducable code so that people can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also make sure you mention the expected output you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you use simple html site without server, database just put content inside swiper code and build your app again